# videoJS load different advertisement (xml) on button click before video

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am setting op a quick presentation where i need to show two advertisements,
I load the videoJs player with all dependencies and to links to click

```
<!-- Load dependent stylesheets. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/videojs-contrib-ads/dist/videojs.ads.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/dist/videojs.ima.css" />

<video id="content_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
       controls preload="auto" width="780" height="440">
    <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gvabox/media/samples/android.mp4"
            type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<div onclick="Select(2)">ad 1</div>
<div onclick="Select(1)">ad 2</div>

<!-- Load dependent scripts -->
<script src="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js"></script>
<script src="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/videojs-contrib-ads/dist/videojs.ads.min.js"></script>
<script src="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/dist/videojs.ima.js"></script>
```

with this I use the following JS

```
var player = videojs('content_video');

function Select(number) {

    if (number == 1) {

        var options = {
            id: 'content_video',
            adTagUrl: 'ad1.xml'
        };

        player.ima(options);

        player.load();

    }

    if (number == 2) {

        var options = {
            id: 'content_video',
            adTagUrl: 'ad2.xml'
        };

        player.ima(options);

        player.load();

    }

}
```

now when the page loads it plays the default android video
when I click on ad1 the player reloads and player with the ad
however when i click on the second ad (not necessary in that order) I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError:player.ima is not a function
```

I understand that I can only load the player.ima once, so how would I in that case update the options and reload the player so I can switch between the ads.

Answer (score 0):

It is because player.ima cannot be called more than one time. The first time you click is working because the ima is only called once. Second time ima already exists.

You may refer to following github link for more details.
https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads/issues/345

Comment: That is what i said in the end. I know it can only be called once.